# Build an ever growing 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function (`MyFunct(X)`) that, depending on the value of `X`, will return *either* a 3D numpy array (e.g `np.ones((5,2,3))` or an empty array (`np.array([])`).

```
RetVal = MyFunct(X) # RetVal can be np.array([]) or np.ones((5,2,3))
```

**NB** I'm using `np.ones((5,2,3))` as a way to generate fake data - in reality the content of the RetVal is all integers.

`MyFunct` is called with a range of different X values, some of which will lead to an empty array being returned while others don't.

I'd like to create a new 3D numpy array (`OUT`) which is an `n` by 2 by 3 concatenated array of all the returned values from `MyFunct()`. This issue is trying to concatenate a 3D array and an empty list causes an exception (understandably!) rather than just silently not doing anything. There are various ways around this:

- Explicitly checking if the `RetVal` is empty or not and then use `np.concatenate()`
- Using a try/except block and catching exceptions
- Adding each value to a list and then post-processing by removing empty entries

But these all feel ugly. Is there an efficient/fast way to do this 'correctly'?

Comment: Growing arrays by concatenation is very expensive, since every concatenation operation forces you to generate a new copy of the entire array. This becomes slower and slower as your array grows larger and larger. In general it's better to either 1) allocate an array larger than you think you need and fill in the rows as you go along, or 2) collect the subarrays in a list and perform all of the concatenation in a single step.

Comment: `np.zeros((0,2,3))` is just as empty as `np.array([])`, and more compatible with `(n,2,3)` arrays.

Comment: Thanks - the list appending followed by concatenation made a huge difference to performance (which obviously it should!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape arrays to compatible shape :

```
concatenate([MyFunct(X).reshape((-1,2,3)) for X in values])
```

Example :

```
In [2]: def MyFunc(X): return ones((5,2,3)) if X%2 else array([])

In [3]: concatenate([MyFunc(X).reshape((-1,2,3)) for X in range(6)]).shape
Out[3]: (15, 2, 3)
```